# Python Convert Unicode

Tags: python, unicode

When I `print(some_var)` in Python, the output resembles:

```
u"some-id-0\x03some-name-0\x03some-url-0\x02some-id-1\x03some-name-1\x03some-url-1\x02some-user-uuid\x03some-name\x03some-url.com\x02some-user-id\x03some_name\x03some-url.com"
```

Not familiar with unicode, I had expected and **want** the data to be in a list of lists:
`[["some-id-0", "some-name-0", "some-url-0"], ["some-id-1", "some-name-1", "some-url-1], etc]`

How do I implement this in Python?

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension can generate the list of lists:

```
[part.split('\x03') for part in some_var.split('\x02')]
```

Which yields

```
[['some-id-0', 'some-name-0', 'some-url-0'], ['some-id-1', 'some-name-1', 'some-url-1'], ['some-user-uuid', 'some-name', 'some-url.com'], ['some-user-id', 'some_name', 'some-url.com']]
```